# How to model User, Text, Entry tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

The idea is that the user creates entries, and the text doesn't belong to one user, but many entries.  When the user creates a first entry, then a text is created, but doesn't strictly belong to the user. Think of 10 people each writing one line, for one text of 10 lines.  How do I write the migration? Thank you.

Sketch--

```
User
  has many entries
  (has many texts, entries through texts?)

Text
  has many entries

Entry
  belongs to text
  belongs to user

# updated...
User
 has_many :entries
 has_many :texts, :through => :entries

Text
 has_many :entries
 has_many :users, :through => :entries

Entry
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic migrations to match your model associations above would be

```
create_table :users do |t|
  # User Fields
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :texts do |t|
  # Text Fields
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :entries do |t|
  # Entry Fields
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :text_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

You may also need additional fields in the `:entries` table for ordering entries within a text (depending on your application).

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are pretty easy to write once you decide upon the associations between your model

```
User
 has_many :entries
 has_many :texts, :through :entries

Text
 has_many :entries

Entry
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :text
```

The Entry table will have 2 columns for storing the ids of user and text respectively (user_id & text_id) and that's it you can now easily write migration for each of your model...

Comment: What about the texts table? texts_entries? How do I write that?

Comment: If the text is created by the user then you should add one more line to your Text table as belongs_to :user and then your text table will have a column (user_id) storing the id of the user...

Comment: Will you look at my update and help me write the migrations? It's unclear to me what the Text table looks like, or if there is a text table at all, only an entries table?  When the user makes a "new" entry, it sets a new text_id on the entry?  Thanks for helping.